# MS SQL Server - Determine disk space for foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, diskspace

I started to work on a database, which has two quite big tables - like this example (the size is more or less correct):

```
-> dbo.Articles (100 million rows; <10GB)
-> dbo.Prices   ( 10 billion rows; <100GB)
```

The Price table has the ID of the Articles, but there is no technical foreign key defined. This causes that there are thousands of unconsistant rows in these tables and some frameworks which we are starting to use "don't like" these non-relational structure.
I prefer the data to be consistent and relational, so I am planning to add a foreign key.

Any ideas how much storage space the foreign key will need and if there will be any performance (dis-)advantages? The IDs are already indexed of course.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key requires just a few bytes of storage space in meta-data.

It requires an index on the columns that are referenced but that seems to be present already.

Foreign key checking is visible in the execution plans for DML which you should check. If the referenced data is in-memory it costs just a little CPU and no IO.

FKs can improve performance because they enable certain query optimizations.

Comment: Good answer already and the answer is what I was hoping in my mind. I guess it's time for some tests with a local db-copy. Thanks a lot.